# Pb to read datamatrix barcode

Tags: codenameone

Codename One :

I'm going back to a project and I'm not at all comfortable with this environment

I have a problem to read Datamartrix barcode. Using zxing.

Somebody have a way ?

Thanks
Dominic

It's OK with QRCODE

```
public static String SCANNER_QR_CODE_TYPE="DATA_MATRIX";//JOPA 14/09/2018 QRCode ident
```

It seem's it's not implemented in scanBarCode() in NativeCodeScannerImpl.java. Only QRCODE.

Comment: Which cn1lib are you using and on which OS? If you are using the codescanner cn1lib which qr scanner app do you have installed?

Comment: This was re-posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54543795/1531971